# how to use the xAxis value to set the center of pie chart in Echarts?

Tags: javascript, center, pie-chart, echarts

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxNz4.jpg)

I'm using Echarts to realize the combination of pie chart and line chart. And I want to use the location of some value of xAxis as the center of each pie chart. e.g. the first pie chart's center is where xAxis's value is 2001.
I search it in google but failed to find an answer for that. Most of the answers just indicate that I should use pixel or percentage to describe the location.

```
var option1 = {
    xAxis: {
        data:[2005,2010,2015,2020]
    },
    yAxis: {},

    series:[
        {
            type:'line',
            data:[12,19,44,33]
        },
        {
            type:'line',
            data:[22,59,84,13]
        }
    ]
};
//......
while(len--){
    option1.series.push({
        type:'pie',
        radius:15,
        center:['xx%',200],
        data:[
            {value:335, name:'item1'},   
            {value:310, name:'item2'},
            {value:140, name:'item3'}
            ]
    })
}
```

The code I post above I use percentage to describe the center of a pie chart, but what I want to realize is to locate my center with xAxis value of line chart, e.g. the center of the first pie chart should be(2005,12).

Comment: Hi Lilian, can you share some of your code? It will help others in helping you. It can be in a code sandbox like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or you can add the code to your post.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of this! I've posted some of my code there.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this example maybe useful: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=calendar-pie, it shows how to get the coordinates and place pie charts into cells.